# How do I display some but not all JSON data in a list view in Android JAVA

Tags: java, android, json, listview, url

I am trying to display some but not all of the info from a JSON file which I have retrieved using a URL, into a list view in Android JAVA.  The JSON has lots of fields but I only want two of them.  I have managed to do the same app in iOS and had to make the fields optional but am unsure how to do this in Android.

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ListView lv;

String username, online;

private static String JSON_URL = "http://**.***.**.***:*****/userconfig";

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> usersList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    usersList = new ArrayList<>();
    lv = findViewById(R.id.listView);

    GetData getData = new GetData();
    getData.execute();


}

public class GetData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String current = "";

        try {
            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

            try {
                url = new URL(JSON_URL);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(in);

                int data = isr.read();
                while (data != -1) {

                    current += (char) data;
                    data = isr.read();

                }

                return current;

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (urlConnection != null) {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

            return current;
        }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("users");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                username = jsonObject1.getString("username");
                online = jsonObject1.getString("online");

                //Hashmap
                HashMap<String, String> friends = new HashMap<>();

                friends.put("username", username);
                friends.put("online", online);

                usersList.add(friends);


            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Display the results

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                MainActivity.this,
                usersList,
                R.layout.row_layout,
                new String[] {"username", "online"},
                new int[]{R.id.textView, R.id.textView2});

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like there's a way to do this using SimpleAdapter (that I've been able to find). You could do this with a custom adapter for your ListView. You'd do this by making an adapter class extending from ArrayAdapter or BaseAdapter (looks like a sample implementation for reference here: [ListView ArrayAdapter, hiding children inside Row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897480/listview-arrayadapter-hiding-children-inside-row)). Then in your getView implementation you could check for the entries you want to hide and set the visibility for them accordingly.